# Is it possible to get from python code bandwidth using curl library?

Tags: python, curl, bandwidth

I know, that it is easy to set max upload and max download:

```
_curl = pycurl.Curl()
_curl.setopt(pycurl.MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, max_send_speed)
_curl.setopt(pycurl.MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, max_recv_speed)
```

How can I get the bandwidth ? For example, I started to download a file and after downloading I want to see 10 Mb/s - speed of my internet connection.

Comment: You could query the current time before and after the libcurl operation, get the content's size, and compute thus the bandwidth

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch
hey, thanks for your answer. I have a question - how can I get the content's size? Is it possible to use curl without calculating the size of file ?

Comment: The HTTP reply probably got a `Content-Size`. You should read more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (and [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)...) and about [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)